# MySQLSyntaxErrorException though everything seems fine (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have a Project entity and a Group entity. I can get a Project by name using the following getter method from DAO:

```
public Project getProject(String name){
    Project project = null;

    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Project.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", name));
    List<Project> projects = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
    if ((projects != null) && (projects.size() > 0)) {
        project = (Project)projects.get(0);
    }
    return project;
}
```

Whereas this very same build doesn't work for the group DAO:

```
public Group getGroup(String name){
    Group group = null;

    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Group.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", name));
    List<Group> groups = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
    if ((groups != null) && (groups.size() > 0)) {
        group = (Group)groups.get(0);
    }
    return group;
}
```

Here's the stack trace that goes (this appears when I try to create a new group; a group with supplied name is fetched to check if such a group already exists and throw an exception if so):

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'group this_
>   where this_.name='new_group'' at line
>   1
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>     java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3494)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1960)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2114)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2696)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2105)
>     com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2264)
>     org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:187)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1791)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2217)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2108)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2103)
>     org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
>     org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1570)
>     org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
>     org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$35.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:984)
>     org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:372)
>     org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:974)
>     org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:967)
>     pl.edu.agh.adam.core.projects.dao.GroupDAO.getGroup(GroupDAO.java:65)
>     pl.edu.agh.adam.core.projects.GroupService.createGroup(GroupService.java:76)
>     pl.edu.agh.adam.core.projects.web.CreateGroupBean.create(CreateGroupBean.java:80)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
>     com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
>     org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:83)
>     javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:88)
>     org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:100)
>     javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:890)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:234)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1202)
>     javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:623)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:35)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:143)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:93)
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
>     org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
>     org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

Here are the entities (getters and setters omitted):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
public class Group implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Transient
    public static final String REF = "Group";

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = pl.edu.agh.adam.core.account.hibernate.User.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "group_user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    Set<User> users;

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = pl.edu.agh.adam.core.projects.hibernate.Role.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "project_group_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"))
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    Map<Project, Role> projectRoles;

    @Transient
    public static final String PROP_ID = "id";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private Long id;

    @Transient
    public static final String PROP_NAME = "name";
    @Column(name = "name", length = 25, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Transient
    public static final String PROP_PASSWORD = "password";

    @Column(name = "password", length = 40)
    private String password;

    @Transient
    public static final String PROP_SUBSCRIBABLE = "subscribable";

    @Column(name = "subscribable")
    private Boolean subscribable;
}
```

The other one (working one):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Transient
public static final String REF = "Project";

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = pl.edu.agh.adam.core.projects.hibernate.Tag.class)
@JoinTable(name = "project_tag", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
private List<Tag> tags;

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = pl.edu.agh.adam.core.projects.hibernate.Group.class)
@JoinTable(name = "project_group_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"))
private Set<Group> groups;

@ManyToMany(targetEntity = pl.edu.agh.adam.core.projects.hibernate.Role.class)
@JoinTable(name = "project_group_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles;


@Transient
public static final String PROP_ID = "id";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "project_id")
private Long id;

@Transient
public static final String PROP_NAME = "name";
@Column(name = "name", length = 60, unique = true, nullable = false)
private String name;

@Transient
public static final String PROP_SHORTNAME = "shortname";

@Column(name = "shortname", length = 25, unique = true)
private String shortname;

@Transient
public static final String PROP_HOMEPAGE = "homepage";
@Column(name = "homepage", length = 60)
private String homepage;

@Transient
public static final String PROP_DESCRIPTION = "description";
@Column(name = "description", columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
private String description;

  }
```

Also the table structures:
group:
-group_id int(11) auto increment, not null
-name varchar(25) unique, not null
-password varchar(40)
-subscribable tinyint(1)

project

-project_id int(11) auto increment, not null
-name varchar(60) unique, not null
-shortname varchar(25)
-homepage varchar(25)
-description text

I've turned on hibernate query logging to System.out; it the following are produced:

```
select
    this_.project_id as project1_3_0_,
    this_.description as descript2_3_0_,
    this_.homepage as homepage3_0_,
    this_.name as name3_0_,
    this_.shortname as shortname3_0_ 
from
    project this_ 
where
    this_.name=?
```

And the not working one:

```
select
    this_.group_id as group1_4_0_,
    this_.name as name4_0_,
    this_.password as password4_0_,
    this_.subscribable as subscrib4_4_0_ 
from

group this_ where
    this_.name=?
```

What is going on?? :(

Comment: Does the second query run when pasted in a SQL client?

Comment: No it doesn't, which isn't much of a surprise, though I can't tell at a glance, what's wrong with it. Moreover - how can I make hibernate generate a different one?

Comment: I wasn't expecting it to work, but it's easier to "debug" something in a sql client (remove aliases, remove columns, etc). Anyway, I think I found the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't spot that immediately but `group` is a reserved keyword so the generated query is indeed incorrect. Use another table name for the `Group` entity. For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group implements Serializable {

    //...
}
```

Comment: Damn me if that's not right. Is there any other use of the word GROUP apart from GROUP BY? If not, the word should be usable. 
I'm pretty reluctant when it comes to modifying the database, so I've done this:
  `@Table(name="\`group\`")`
Now everytghing works like a charm. Thanks a lot for spotting this for me :)

Comment: @sammy: Indeed, this will work (and is actually better if you don't want to change the database). I personally try to avoid reserved keywords but your solution is fine.

Comment: Ah, you helped me as well. My reserved word was "index". :-)